# 2 dimensional for loop gone wrong

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a 2 dimensional for loop to store every row and column from a DataGridView to a SQL database, with the same sequence of the rows. But when I save it in the database, it becomes repeated over and over.

Let's say I have 5 columns and 3 rows, what I wanted was to have 3 rows stored with the same sequence but it stores 15 repeated sequences.

Here is my code. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('SIV-" & (TextBox4.Text) + 1 & "',0," & j + 1 & ",(select nodeno from productmast where arabic_name= '" & DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value & "')," & DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value & ",0.000000,'2019-04-04 13:40:00'," & DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value & "," & DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value & ",'',0,1,1,1,1,'04/04/2019 13:39:44','',1.000000,1,0,'','b',0.000000,5,0.000000," & DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value & ",'Nos',1.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',0,3,'" & Label4.Text & "',1,1,1,1,1,1,0.000000)"
        'DataGridView1.Item(i, 2).Value
        'DataGridView1.Item()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters and execute the command only once for each loop over the rows, not once for every column AND row

Comment: Better yet, just [databind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).  That's what the "data" part in "DataGridView" is all about...

Comment: You are not even using "j", you hard coded the columns number. Just remove the column loop. Also, search on how to use parameters.

Comment: @the_lotus I figured. That was true my bad...

Comment: Also, turn `Option Strict On` because code like `(TextBox4.Text) + 1` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, I hope this can help.

```
For MyRows As Integer = 0 To 3
        For MyCols As Integer = 0 To 5
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('" & DataGridView1.Rows(MyRows).Cells(MyCols).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(MyRows).Cells(MyCols + 1).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(MyRows).Cells(MyCols + 2).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(MyRows).Cells(MyCols + 3).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(MyRows).Cells(MyCols + 4).Value & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Next
```

Best Regards
    ^_^